# Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker

Wewn I'm trying to docker-compose my required.yml file I'm facing this error

> Error response from daemon: open \.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The
> system cannot find the file specified

I tried this procces in Parallel Desktop (Windows) on my Mac PC. What should I do? Anyone know anything?

I restarted my pc but I can't solve the problem.